# Does antlr automatically discard whitespace?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I've written the following arithmetic grammar:

```
grammar Calc;

program
    : expressions
    ;

expressions
    : expression (NEWLINE expression)*
    ;


expression
    : '(' expression ')'            // parenExpression has highest precedence
    | expression MULDIV expression  // then multDivExpression
    | expression ADDSUB expression  // then addSubExpression
    | OPERAND                       // finally the operand itself
    ;

MULDIV
    : [*/]
    ;

ADDSUB
    : [-+]
    ;

// 12 or .12 or 2. or 2.38
OPERAND
    : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)?
    | '.' [0-9]+
    ;

NEWLINE
    : '\n'
    ;
```

And I've noticed that regardless of how I space the tokens I get the same result, for example:

```
1+2
2+3
```

Or:

```
1       +2
  2+3
```

Still give me the same thing. Also I've noticed that adding in the following rule does nothing for me:

```
WS
   : [ \r\n\t] + -> skip
```

Which makes me wonder whether skipping whitespace is the default behavior of antlr4?

[image]

Comment: Did you actually look at the error messages ANTLR produced? Or did you just grab the parse tree?

Comment: @Sweeper what do you mean? There is no error message it is parsed successfully, I'm just curious why it acts the same in both scenarios.

Comment: @Sweeper I've added a screenshot of the parsing.

Comment: If you are using the default settings, the parse tree are the same in both scenarios, but it also produces lexer errors in if you don't `skip` whitespace. What is that tool that you are using? Is it an online tool? I wonder if your tool is actually *designed* to show you any errors at all. Does `1+` or `1a+3` produce errors?

Comment: @Sweeper `1+` produces errors, but `1a+3` works, and the parseTree is just `1+3`. Though I do get a lexer warning: `Lexer error (1, 5): token recognition error at: 'x',<unknown>,1,4,true`

Comment: @Sweeper oh, got it now! Yes, it's producing warnings, I just wasn't noticing them. For example: https://gyazo.com/b5a2a21c08955c45f488217c11acfb94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR4 based parsers have the ability to skip over single unwanted or missing tokens and continue parsing if possible (which is the case here). And there's no default to ignore whitespaces. You have to always specify a whitespace rule which either skips them or puts them on a hidden channel.